# *** ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have app that is hosted with phusion passanger. App seems to work just fine for me, but sometimes it just shutdowns. Recently I created Cron task that acceses root page each minute so the Passanger wouldn't go to sleep.

It seems to do the work. Spawn time are just litle.

When app shutdowns I tried theese comands suggested by Google search.

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

no output no change

```
passenger-config restart-app /darbs
```

Output:
 ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running.*

App log files doesn't show any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the Passenger temp directory is being removed by your OS, causing a malfunction. Try setting PassengerTempDir to a different place: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerTempDir

Comment: This helped me solve a very similar problem while running Passenger with Apache httpd 2.4. For me, the solution was to edit httpd.service to disable the private tmp folder: `PrivateTmp=false`. There's probably a better way to fix this.